# Highlighting a query word in a document

Tags: algorithm

I have a document and a query term. I want to

1. find the query term in the document.
2. Pad each occurrence of the query term with a certain text marker.

For example

```
Text:   I solemnly swear that I am upto no good.
Query:  swear

Output: I solemnly MATCHSTART swear MATCHEND that I am upto no good.
```

Assuming that I have multiple query words and a large document, now can I do this efficiently.

I did go over various links on the internet but couldn't find anything very conclusive or definite. Moreover, this is just a programming question and has nothing to do with search engine development or information retrieval.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Using your favourite language use something like `text.replaceAll('swear','MATCHSTART swear MATCHEND')`. Note, it also finds `swearing`.

Comment: -1 since no mention of a language..can't really answer if we don't know how you are trying to accomplish this.

Comment: You couldn't find "replace" functionality anywhere on the internet?

Comment: text.Replace().. I think, you never work with real big data. When need highlight all chemical compound names (~400,000 keywords) in the while pub-archive (~60gigs of text files). How long time will work your text.Replace()?

Answer (score 1):

If each your query is word (some substring, does not contains SP/TAB/NL, etc), and allowed with very low probability false positive (when you mark some word, omitted in the query set) - you can use Bloom filter: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter

First, load your query words into Bloom filter, and thereafter scan document, and match each word in the filter. If search result is positive - mark this word.

You can use my implementation of bloom filter: http://olegh.cc.st/src/bloom.c.txt

Comment: Very nice, and well commented!  With your permission, may I use this code with a GPL license (in combination with other GPL-licensed code)?

Comment: Yes, you can. This code had been written for another OpenSource project, and can be used/distributed free. Just don't remove my name as author.

Answer (score 0):

In Python:

```
text = "I solemnly swear I am up to no good" #read in however you like.
query = input("Query: ")
text.replace(" "+query" "," MATCHSTART "+query+" MATCHEND ")

OUTPUT:
'I solemnly MATCHSTART swear MATCHEND that I am up to no good.'
```

You could also use regex, but that's slower, so I just used string concat to add whitespace to the beginning and end of the word (so as not to match "swears" or "swearing" or "sportswear". This is easily translatable to whatever language you prefer.